# Modified JavaScript Step output fields are empty

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am assigning strings to 3 variables inside a Modified JS step and then trying to pass them to another step. When I click test script and then OK the columns show with the code (string) I need. When I click Preview everything is empty. When I run the transformation or click Preview on a step it seems to data which should be passed in those fields is empty. I just need the strings inside the JS step to get passed further to the next step (metadata injection). Any idea why that is and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, without knowing what you are exactly doing..... Might be best to add script, and step settings in the question.

Most common mistakes:

1. **Output field not declared:**

All new/overwritten outgoing fields need to be designated in the bottom of the step

[image]

2. **Error in the javascript**

If the javascript has some error, for example not storing the result in a variable, then it offcoarse also will not be outputted in the step itsself.

Comment: This is the code inside the step:
https://wtools.io/paste-code/bPRr

Comment: From here I am passing the SQL fields to a metadata injection step to which send the code to table input steps. The var containing the fields is sent to the metadata injeciton step too